# Creating a Normal Image With Matlab

Tags: matlab, normals

Using Matlab, I have 3 matrices that comprise of x, y and z coordinates respectively. Let's call them A, B and C (A has a 768x1024 matrix of all the x elements, B of all the y elements and C of all the z elements). These are all 768 x 1024 images. They are essentially the elements of the normal vector at each pixel.

```
A = 768x1024
B = 768x1024
C = 768x1024

Result I want = a 768x1024 matrix that has a color map intensity to show the direction of the normal vector at each pixel.
```

So I want to create a normal map image that is 768x1024 that shows the normal mapping at each pixel using the x, y, z coordinates. I was wondering how you would go about doing that in Matlab. Kind of similar to this: https://www.google.com/search?q=normal+map+image&espv=2&biw=1266&bih=641&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXybLQpJvKAhXKOiYKHVP-DoIQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=mxx6Z4GDfTcczM%3A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `surfnorm`

```
[nx,ny,nz] = surfnorm(A,B,C);
img = reshape([nx ny nz], size(nx,1), size(nx,2),3); //range [-1,1]
img = ((img+1)./2).*255; //range [0,255]
imshow(uint8(img));
```

Comment: what does b represent there?

Comment: it was a mistake: b ==> img.